# C# how to object created in Btn_click event access by another Btn_Click

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using the VS2010 C# language.

I have a form with ENTER button which create an object of class ORDER in Enter_Click(..) event. Now I have another button ADD ITEM which suppose to add a new item in an order when it is clicked.

I tried to access an Order object created in ENTER button click event, in ADDITEM_Click(..) event, I got the following error:

"Object does not exist in current context"

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your Order is limited to the `Enter_Click()` event because that is where you declare it. Add the line `Order myOrder` at the class level and it will work because the object will continue to exist after the `Enter_Click()` method finishes.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the `Order`object in scope of `Class` which contain `Enter Button Event Handler` and `Add Button Event Handler`

For example

```
partial class MyFormClass 
{
    Order myOrder;

    EnterButton_Click(....)
    {
       myOrder = new Order();
    }

   AddButton_Click(....)
   {
      myOrder.Add(....);
   }
}
```